# Multiple models in one class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm referencing two models in one controller.  Can I combine the models into one .cs file or do they need to be separate?  It just seems that I could keep things cleaner by putting them in one file.

Comment: If models are small and related, than they can be stored in one file.

Comment: Can you provide a basic example on how this is done? @Alexander

Comment: short answer is yes, you can, but sounds like should and there really isn't an answer to this question.  It is just a matter of opinion.  I will tell you that most developers prefer to keep them separate and mainly for solution navigation purposes.  I care not

Comment: Thanks @RobA.  Good to know about other practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course! You can create one file with several models. It's usually used for models, which refer to the same entity or controller. The `AccountModels.cs` file example:

```
using System;

namespace SolutionName.Web.Models
{
    public class LogOnModel { /*parameters*/ }

    public class RegisterModel { /*parameters*/ }

    public class ChangePasswordModel { /*parameters*/ }
}
```

And sometimes you can create one model inside other. You can do this when you have a little model, which depends on other one and using only for the "paren" model.

**For example:**

```
using System;

namespace SolutionName.Web.Models
{
    public class StartPageViewModel
    {   
        public HeaderViewModel Header { get; set; }
        public BodyViewModel Header { get; set; }
        public FooterViewModel Header { get; set; }

                  /*parameters*/

        class HeaderViewModel { /*parameters*/ }

        class BodyViewModel { /*parameters*/ }

        class FooterViewModel { /*parameters*/ }
    }
}
```